# Python get the x first words in a string

Tags: python, string

I'm looking for a code that takes the 4 (or 5) first words in a script.
I tried this:

```
import re    
my_string = "the cat and this dog are in the garden"    
a = my_string.split(' ', 1)[0]
b = my_string.split(' ', 1)[1]
```

But I can't take more than 2 strings:

```
a = the
b = cat and this dog are in the garden
```

I would like to have:

```
a = the
b = cat
c = and
d = this
...
```

Comment: please read the documentation for the parameters of split ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The second argument of the `split()` method is the limit. Don't use it and you will get all words.
Use it like this:

```
my_string = "the cat and this dog are in the garden"    
splitted = my_string.split()

first = splitted[0]
second = splitted[1]

...
```

Also, don't call `split()` every time when you want a word, it is expensive. Do it once and then just use the results later, like in my example.
As you can see, there is no need to add the `' '` delimiter since the default delimiter for the `split()` function (`None`) matches all whitespace. You can use it however if you don't want to split on `Tab` for example.

Comment: Minor: `' '` isn't the default delimiter; the default value is `None`, which splits on consecutive whitespace.  Compare `'a  b'.split()` with `'a  b'.split(' ')`.

Comment: @DSM: you are right, i expressed myself wrong, i ment to say it will work for space. I will update my answer.

Comment: Better yet: Compare `'a \tb'.split()` and `'a \tb'.split(' ')`!

Comment: @bosnjak Is there anything faster than split() in python if I just need to get first and last word from string. It seems like to much work to split whole string in such cases.

Comment: @Naman sure, both `split` and `rsplit` have a second argument that is `maxsplit`. So to get the first word, use `sentence.split(' ',1)` and to get the last word use `sentence.rsplit(' ',1)`. This should be what you need.

Comment: Or again for broader whitespace constraints `sentence.rsplit(None, 1)` which gets you back to the default behavior of `split()` while still invoking the 2nd arg

Answer (score 38):

You can use **slice notation** on the list created by split:

```
my_string.split()[:4] # first 4 words
my_string.split()[:5] # first 5 words
```

N.B. these are example commands. You should use one or the other, not both in a row.

Comment: This works, but it calls the `split()` method multiple times. You should not do this, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: This doesn't call `split` multiple times. It calls it once and creates a `slice copy` of the list it returns. This is why `l2 = l1[:]` is a valid way to make a copy of a list in Python. It does not create `n` sublists.

Comment: Ah i see where you are going with this, yours was just an example, not two consecutive commands, which wouldn't made any sense. I was thinking why you would have both lines when you can only have the second one, but I was running to conclusion. Got it.

Comment: Ah, yes. It's not so you can use both. It's so you can use whichever command depending on if OP actually wants the first 4 or 5 members. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can split a string on whitespace easily enough, but if your string doesn't happen to have enough words in it, the assignment will fail where the list is empty.

```
a, b, c, d, e = my_string.split()[:5] # May fail
```

You'd be better off keeping the list as is instead of assigning each member to an individual name.

```
words = my_string.split()
at_most_five_words = words[:5] # terrible variable name
```

That's a terrible variable name, but I used it to illustrate the fact that you're not guaranteed to get five words – you're only guaranteed to get *at most* five words.